# Custom admin module access denied for user role with less privillages

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have a custom module that works fine if you are an admin user. If I have a user with limited permissions and allow them to access the custom module, they can see the admin menu, but when they click on it, they get Access denied. I believe something is wrong with the ACL.

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Freshproduce_Careers>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Freshproduce_Careers>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <careers>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Freshproduce_Careers</module>
            <frontName>careers</frontName>
          </args>
      </careers>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <careers>
              <file>careers.xml</file>
            </careers>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <careers>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Freshproduce_Careers</module>
                <frontName>careers</frontName>
            </args>
        </careers>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <freshproduce module="careers">
            <title>Fresh Produce</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <careers module="careers">
                    <title>Careers</title>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                    <action>careers/adminhtml_careers</action>
                </careers>
            </children>
        </freshproduce>
    </menu>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <careers>
                <file>careers.xml</file>
            </careers>
        </updates>
    </layout>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                    <all>
                        <title>Allow Everything</title>
                    </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                         <freshproduce>
                            <children>
                                <careers>
                                    <title>Careers</title>
                                </careers>
                            </children>
                        </freshproduce>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
  </adminhtml>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <careers>
        <class>Freshproduce_Careers_Helper</class>
      </careers>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <careers>
        <class>Freshproduce_Careers_Block</class>
      </careers>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <careers>
            <class>Freshproduce_Careers_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>careers_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </careers>
        <careers_mysql4>
            <class>Freshproduce_Careers_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <careers>
                    <table>careers</table>
                </careers>
            </entities>
        </careers_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <careers_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Freshproduce_Careers</module>
                <class>Freshproduce_Careers_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>

            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </careers_setup>

        <careers_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </careers_write>
        <careers_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </careers_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

[image]

I also tried add this code to my admin controller, but didn't seem to have any effect:

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('careers');
}
```

I have read the Alan Storm article on ACL: http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication

and yet this still doesn't work. If someone can help me I would be happy to share more code or dig into the core if anyone knows where to look for the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACL path for your module declares as freshproduce/careers so you should be verifying the access is allowed against that rather than against careers. See the modified _isAllowed below which has the proper ACL path in it.

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('freshproduce /careers');
}
```